# For each ajax request,PHP return different results based on the time row was created

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an ajax loop that returns recently created profiles from PHP encoded for JSON.
 What i want to do is first return the most recently created profile and go to the second recently created profile and so on every time ajax sends a request to PHP.

How do i do this. So far the ajax loop just returns the same result since i can only get one recently created profile.

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php 
require_once 'db_conx.php';
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles ORDER BY lastupdated desc limit 1")
 or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)){
$result = array();
$result['logo'] = $row['logo'];
$result['name'] = $row['name'];
echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
```

In the above php Block, if i remove 'limit 1' to something else, the ajax just stops working altogether.

Here's my ajax code:

```
get_fb();
var get_fb = (function(){
    var counter = 0;
    var $buzfeed = $('#BuzFeed');
    return function(){
        $.ajax({
            dataType : 'json',
            type: "GET",
            url: "../php/TopBusinesses_Algorythm.php"
        }).done(function(feedback) {
            counter += 1;
            var $buzfeedresults = 
$("<div style='margin-bottom:2px'><input name='1' type='submit' id='LogLogo' value=' '><span id='name' style='float:right; height:21px;font-weight:bold; color:#000; width:71%' class='goog-flat-menu-button'><span class='LogName'></span></span><span id='slogan'><span class='LogSlogan'></span></span><span id='services'><span class='LogServices'></span></span></div></div><span id='LogPid' style='height:170px; background-image:url(images/bg/iWhiteBg.fw.png)'></span></div>");
            $('.LogName').html(feedback.name).attr('id' + counter);
           $( '.LogSlogan' ).html(feedback.slogan);
           $('.LogPId').html(feedback.pid);
           $('.LogLogo').css('background-image', 'url(' + feedback.logo + ')' ).css('background-size', 'cover')         
            $buzfeedresults.append(feedback);
            $buzfeed.append($buzfeedresults);
            var $buzfeedDivs = $buzfeed.children('div');
            if ($buzfeedDivs.length > 7) { $buzfeedDivs.last().remove(); }
            setTimeout(get_fb, 2000);
        })
        });
    };
})();
get_fb();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you output several JSON strings on the page try something like this:

```
<?php 
require_once 'db_conx.php';
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles ORDER BY lastupdated desc limit 10") or die (mysql_error());
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)){
    $result['logo'] = $row['logo'];
    $result['name'] = $row['name'];
    $results[]=$result;
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in following ways:

1. declare counter variable globally(outside of get_fb() function) so that it will hold actual ajax call count
2. pass this counter value to ajax request
3. receive this counter value at your php end and use it as offset value to your sql(ex. limit offset,1)

======

## edit

```
var counter = 0;
var get_fb = (function(){

    var $buzfeed = $('#BuzFeed');
    return function(){
        $.ajax({
            dataType : 'json',
            type: "GET",
            url: "../php/TopBusinesses_Algorythm.php?counter="+counter
        }).done(function(feedback) {
            counter += 1;
            var $buzfeedresults = 
$("<div style='margin-bottom:2px'><input name='1' type='submit' id='LogLogo' value=' '><span id='name' style='float:right; height:21px;font-weight:bold; color:#000; width:71%' class='goog-flat-menu-button'><span class='LogName'></span></span><span id='slogan'><span class='LogSlogan'></span></span><span id='services'><span class='LogServices'></span></span></div></div><span id='LogPid' style='height:170px; background-image:url(images/bg/iWhiteBg.fw.png)'></span></div>");
            $('.LogName').html(feedback.name).attr('id' + counter);
           $( '.LogSlogan' ).html(feedback.slogan);
           $('.LogPId').html(feedback.pid);
           $('.LogLogo').css('background-image', 'url(' + feedback.logo + ')' ).css('background-size', 'cover')         
            $buzfeedresults.append(feedback);
            $buzfeed.append($buzfeedresults);
            var $buzfeedDivs = $buzfeed.children('div');
            if ($buzfeedDivs.length > 7) { $buzfeedDivs.last().remove(); }
            setTimeout(get_fb, 2000);
        })
        });
    };
})();
get_fb();


<?php 
require_once 'db_conx.php';
$counter = $_REQUEST['counter'];
if(!$counter)$counter=0;
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles ORDER BY lastupdated desc limit $counter,1")
 or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)){
$result = array();
$result['logo'] = $row['logo'];
$result['name'] = $row['name'];
echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
```

=========

## edit

```
var $buzfeedresults = 
$("<div style='margin-bottom:2px'><input name='1' type='submit' id='LogLogo"+counter+"' value=' '><span id='name' style='float:right; height:21px;font-weight:bold; color:#000; width:71%' class='goog-flat-menu-button'><span class='LogName' id='log_name"+counter+"'></span></span><span id='slogan'><span class='LogSlogan' id='log_slogan"+counter+"'></span></span><span id='services'><span class='LogServices'></span></span></div></div><span id='LogPid"+counter+"' style='height:170px; background-image:url(images/bg/iWhiteBg.fw.png)'></span></div>");
            $('#log_name'+counter).html(feedback.name);
           $( '#log_slogan'+counter ).html(feedback.slogan);
           $('#LogPId'+counter).html(feedback.pid);
           $('#LogLogo'+counter).css('background-image', 'url(' + feedback.logo + ')' ).css('background-size', 'cover')
```

Comment: this is the logic, you just need to make it workable according to your needs

Comment: Ok this does some stuff, so now here's the new problem that our code does, for every new div created by ajax, all the divs change to have contents of the newly created div, i think this is because they have the same class selector, this is some problem i have to say, what do you think i can do here.

Comment: you can use id as selector instead of class so that you can assign new id to each item using the counter variable(ex. id='LogLogo1', id='LogLogo2' ... then $('#LogLogo1') )

Comment: please see my second edit, its actually the part of your code, and please check if i missed anything to put. its just an idea, you need to make it working according to your needs.

Comment: $('#log_name'+counter) this is not appending with the counter, check the syntax, and you didnt match the ids right on the selector and the ids though im aware of that on my testing code still doesnt append.

Answer (score 0):

So i revised the structure of this Feed System and found out an easier way to do this is to generate the html from php.

So here's the PHP with HTML

```
<?php 
require_once 'db_conx.php';
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles ORDER BY lastupdated desc limit 10")
 or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)){
echo '<div style="margin-bottom:2px">
    <span id="name" style="float:right; height:21px;font-weight:bold; color:#000; width:71%">
<span class="LogName">'.$row['name'].'</span>
</span>
<span id="slogan" style="float:right; height:21px;color:#0D1; width:71%" class="goog-flat-menu-button">
<span class="LogSlogan">'.$row['slogan'].'</span>
</span>
<span id="services" style="float:right; height:21px;color:#000; width:71%" class="goog-flat-menu-button">
<span class="LogServices">'.$row['services'].'</span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<span id="ProfileMap" style="height:170px; background-image:url(images/bg/iWhiteBg.fw.png)"></span>
<span id="LogPid" style="height:170px; background-image:url(images/bg/iWhiteBg.fw.png)"></span>
</div>';
}
?>
```

Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"../php/feed.php"
    }).done(function(feedback){
    $('#feed').html(feedback)
});
```

and just one Div of HTML in the body to house the incoming HTML.

```
<body>
<div id='feed'></body>
</body>
```

Done.